# WinSCP overwrites files without asking

Tags: ftp, winscp

Obviously I accidentally hit the "don't ask me again" button when I overwrote some files. How to undo it? I cannot find the setting to make WinSCP ask me next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [WinSCP preferences](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_preferences), on the first [*Environment* page](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_environment), check the *Confirmations > Overwriting of files*.

Note that for background transfers, all confirmations are turned off by default. To enable them, go to [*Transfer > Background* page](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_background) and uncheck the *No confirmations for background transfers*.

Comment: cheez, I had it all way in front of me but missed it. I had already seen about background confirmations, but couldn't find the simple one. Thanks.

Comment: An important setting to change! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This might be an older question which was already answered, but I've found another setting which might be helpful:

In the *preferences* you can go to *Transfer*, there you can click the "*Edit*" button on the "*Default*" *preset description*. Under "*Other*" you can tick the "*New and updated files only*" if that's what you're in to

[image]